# Warning: include(../../inc/functions.php): failed to open stream: no such file or directory

Tags: php, include

This is the situation that I face off, the following is the structure of the site:

```
 index.php
 /inc
    functions.php
 /css
 /img
 /connect
    db.class.php
    setup.php
 /admin
    index.php
    /img
    /css
    /inc
       functions.php
    /connect
       db.class.php
       setup.php 
    /content
       page.php
       /op
         add.php
         modify.php
         delete.php
```

I've tested using absolute and relative paths, **DIR**, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], etc

the problem is when I tried to include the functions.php file from the folder inc to the folder content or op. I've tested in some different ways and checks some answers from here I cannot fixed it.

Could someone fix this issue?

Comment: you have two `inc` folder and both of them has `functions.php`. from which folder you are accessing them?

Comment: your question is not clear and what understand is that check your file name...

Comment: I did it from [op] and [content]

Comment: nope. you are accessing it from a different folder. that's i am sure. check `__DIR__`

Comment: @m4g4bu, Your question hardly makes the issue clear. Make it clearer to get an answer and possibly **upvotes** too. Please improve the formatting of at least the **`CODE` SECTION**.

Comment: @RajeshPaul what's there to edit in `code section`. the formatting is clean as far it can go.

Comment: @m4g4bu You have already **edited** and you are still asking!!! Now it looks better...

Comment: @m4g4bu, have you enclosed `../../inc/functions.php` in a pair of ***single quotation(')*** or not in the `include(../../inc/functions.php)`?

I mean-

`include(../../inc/functions.php)`
or
`include('../../inc/functions.php')`?

Comment: @m4g4bu, already upvoted your question.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I search the web a lot for a question but i did not find any so i did it myself, so here it is:

```
define('GLOBAL_APP_ROOT', $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]); // you can append to this path the folder in which your site is deployed, in case you are working for a new version or something, and when you will deploy it you just delete it

public static function ToAbsolute($path)
{
    $root = GLOBAL_APP_ROOT;
    $cwd = getcwd(); // the current working directory => usually the directory from where the script its being called.
    $cwd = str_replace('\\', '/', $cwd); // sometimes the current working directory is exposed with '\' instead of '/' - this usually happens on localhost
    $path = ltrim($path,'/'); // cleans the left slash if exists => to avoid any writing errors/bugs

    $depthPath = str_replace($root, '', $cwd); // gets the depth path of the current file

    $depth = substr_count($depthPath, "/"); // gets the dept of the current working directory relative to document root

    $relativePrefix = ""; // declaration of the relative prefix path
    for($i = 0; $i < $depth; $i++) // building up the relative prefix
    {
        $relativePrefix = $relativePrefix."../"; // iterating the depth results in going back one folder
    }

    $relativePath = $relativePrefix.$path; // prepend the relative prefix to the absolute file path resulting in the relative path

    return $relativePath;
}
```

I have this function placed in the `root` of the application in the `url.php` file.
When you want to use it is going to be like this:

```
<?php
    require_once('url.php');
    require_once(ToAbsolute('[file_path]'));
?>
```

So always include the `url.php` first everywhere you want to work with it and always `include` it with its `relative path`. All other files you need to `include` just use the function and pass in the `absolute path` of the `file`

**NOTE:**

If for example you have the following structure:

```
[root]
    [admin]
        [index.php]
    [url.php]
    [css]
        [site.css]
```

Inside the `index.php` you have to have something like this for including the `site.css` :

```
<?php
    require_once('../url.php');
    require_once(ToAbsolute('site.css'));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have **missed one `../`** in the path i.e.

you have to **use the following code**-

`include('../../../inc/functions.php')` if you want to include the file **`function.php`** in any file in the folder **`/op`** and to inclued it in a file in the **`/content`** folder then you have to use the following one-

`include('../../inc/functions.php')`

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 index.php
 /inc
    functions.php
 /css
 /img
 /connect
    db.class.php
    setup.php
 /admin
    index.php
    /img
    /css
    /inc
       functions.php
    /connect
       db.class.php
       setup.php 
    /content
       page.php
       /op
         add.php
         modify.php
         delete.php
  * 
 */
//try ABSOLUTE PATHS, see these examples... I considered your folder tree.
//for windows directories
//try this...

echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\index.php";
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\inc\\functions.php";
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\inc\\index.php";
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\connect\\db.class.php";
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\connect\\setup.php";
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\admin\\index.php";
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\admin\\inc\\functions.php";
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\admin\\connect\\db.class.php";
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\admin\\connect\\setup.php";
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\admin\\content\\page.php";
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\admin\\content\\op\\add.php";
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\admin\\content\\op\\modify.php";
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\admin\\content\\op\\delete.php";
```

//if the path is right, always use this to include files. 
   //see if the folder structure is correct, sometimes there is a folder for the project first

```
include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\index.php";
include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\inc\\functions.php";
include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\inc\\index.php";
include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\connect\\db.class.php";
include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\connect\\setup.php";
include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\admin\\index.php";
include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\admin\\inc\\functions.php";
include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\admin\\connect\\db.class.php";
include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\admin\\connect\\setup.php";
include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\admin\\content\\page.php";
include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\admin\\content\\op\\add.php";
include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\admin\\content\\op\\modify.php";
include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "\\admin\\content\\op\\delete.php";
```